# table a getting multiple input value from user update table b different product quantity using php and mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database

i am making a poultry farm project using php and mysql.  i have input daily routine form which is getting value from user like petrol used, water used, medicine used all values getting as integer and saving on Table A.

I want to update Table B according values getting from table a. like used diesel value subtract and update in table b. as its is other values according with same value subtract from table b.

i tried many ways but failed

Comment: Please show us the code you are talking about. (And is it related to JavaScript also as the tag indicates or just php / mySql?)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see what you need to give us. After you make a good attempt at doing this yourself and if you still have problems, you can update your question with details of the specific problem and what you have tried to solve it, and include your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we are able to help.